# JBoss Seam project can not be runed/deployed JBoss Server 7.1

Tags: jboss, seam

I created sample application in Seam framework (Seam Web Project) and JBoss Server 7.1. When I try run application, console dislays:

```
23:29:35,419 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."secoundProject-ds.xml".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."secoundProject-ds.xml".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "secoundProject-ds.xml"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: local-tx-datasource
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ParserException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: local-tx-datasource
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parseDataSources(DsParser.java:183)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:119)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:80)
    ... 6 more

23:29:35,452 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment secoundProject-ds.xml in 1ms
23:29:35,455 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015863: Replacement of deployment "secoundProject-ds.xml" by deployment "secoundProject-ds.xml" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"secoundProject-ds.xml\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"secoundProject-ds.xml\".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"secoundProject-ds.xml\""}}
23:29:35,457 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "secoundProject-ds.xml"
23:29:35,920 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."secoundProject-ds.xml".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."secoundProject-ds.xml".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "secoundProject-ds.xml"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: local-tx-datasource
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ParserException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: local-tx-datasource
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parseDataSources(DsParser.java:183)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:119)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:80)
    ... 6 more

23:29:35,952 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."secoundProject-ds.xml".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."secoundProject-ds.xml".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "secoundProject-ds.xml"
```

My secoundProject-ds.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE datasources
    PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS JCA Config 1.5//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-ds_1_5.dtd">
<datasources>

   <local-tx-datasource>
      <jndi-name>secoundProjectDatasource</jndi-name>
      <use-java-context>true</use-java-context>
      <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database</connection-url>
      <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
      <user-name>root</user-name>
      <password></password>
   </local-tx-datasource>

</datasources>
```

When I comment tags errors disappear, but application is disabled in browser (`The requested resource (/secoundProject/) is not available.`). What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: repaired broken link to datasource example.

The problem is that you are using old way of datasource definition. Use [this](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Example_MySQL_Datasource1.html) example as a starting point.

Also, use [these](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Migration_Guide/index.html) docs to migrate you Seam app to jbossas-7

Comment: Example page not found. Could you paste it again please?